# Using wildcards in automake

Tags: c++, automake

I have the following makefile.am:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = prog
DEFS =
CFLAGS =
prog_SOURCES := $(wildcard src/GUI_dialogs.cpp) src/GUI_main_win.cpp
$(info **$(prog_SOURCES)**)
```

If I generate the makefile (`autoreconf && ./configure`) and then run `make`

I get the following output:

```
**src/GUI_dialogs.cpp src/GUI_main_win.cpp**
g++  -I.     -g -O2 -MT GUI_main_win.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/GUI_main_win.Tpo -c -o GUI_main_win.o `test -f 'src/GUI_main_win.cpp' || echo './'`src/GUI_main_win.cpp
src/GUI_main_win.cpp:1:24: fatal error: ...Header not found as expected...
```

The first line shows the `prog_SOURCES` variable is set correctly, yet it misses compiling the GUI_dialogs object first.

If I change prog_SOURCES to:

```
 prog_SOURCES := src/GUI_dialogs.cpp src/GUI_main_win.cpp
```

Then the GUI_dialogs object compiles first as expected.

I know the order may not be defined. But if I just have the wildcard there:

```
prog_SOURCES := $(wildcard src/GUI_dialogs.cpp)
```

Then I get:

```
**src/GUI_dialogs.cpp**
gcc     -o prog   
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Why is it just skipping out the wildcard files? Even though it is clearly in the variable?

Comment: By doing this you violate the autotools source policy and apparently break out of source builds. Is this intended?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html

Comment: I don't really care how, but I really do not want to have to manage the list of source files. Yes as that web page says I am a lazy developer. if I wasn't lazy I'd be writing the makefile manually and not using autotools. The current system I'm working with has a shell script which generates the Makefile.am and then uses autotools to generate the makefile. I'd like to remove that shell script.

Comment: Is it possible to just write the makefile directly yet not have to manage dependencies manually (or with ugly, almost indecipherable code directly in the makefile)?

Comment: @user3159253, I don't see why the automake tool needs to know about the files being compiled?

Comment: Well, it generates a separate compilation rule for each source file.

Comment: And yes, it's possible to use just `make` and `gcc -MM` feature to generate the whole bunch of dependencies. Maybe not that convenient, but it's possible. Have you considered [CMake](http://cmake.org). It has better support for globbing in file lists, although it still considers usage of globs as bad practice.

Comment: Here's my answer (in Spanish, sorry, but the code talks) for the case when all the dependencies are handled by make: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1898/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-makefile-que-calcule-las-dependencias/1929#1929

Comment: @user3159253, I don't see that when I run it,maybe I'm just missing it.Tbh I'm not completely sure what automake does and what autoconf does. (i know what they both do overall).

Comment: @user3159253 I have considered CMake, but it seems unable to handle custom language files (without specifically listed each one). I have a bunch of files that need to be compiled to cpp and h files and then those can be compiled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109177/discussion-between-user3159253-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 1):

Was running into a similar issue, from the docs it looks like it's not a good idea.

https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html

"Even if you don’t care about portability, and are tempted to use ‘$(wildcard ...)’ anyway because you target only GNU Make, you should know there are many places where Automake needs to know exactly which files should be processed. As Automake doesn’t know how to expand ‘$(wildcard ...)’, you cannot use it in these places. ‘$(wildcard ...)’ is a black box comparable to AC_SUBSTed variables as far Automake is concerned.

You can get warnings about ‘$(wildcard ...’) constructs using the -Wportability flag."